# Amazon EC2: map on it some of my network's folders

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I have an application that does some processing on different files.  The jobs are prepared on one machine, and then assigned to other machines where they are executed.

I'd like to be able to run some machines from the Amazon cloud.  The tricky part is that machine will be told to process let's say t:\folder\file1.ext and \mymachine\file2.ext.  These are locations on my network, so a Windows app running on Amazon cloud won't know where those files are.

Is there some sort of magical tool out there so the cloud machine could access these locations by the same name as a machine on my network would?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some sort of magical tool out there so the cloud machine could access these locations by the same name as a machine on my network would?

Yes. [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) paired with a IPSec VPN connection to your corporate network.  This will allow your AWS resources to function as an extension of your existing network.  Be warned though: it's not for the faint of heart to configure.